# Proof: Indepence of path of integration for line integral of second type

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the line integral of the second type:

$$
I = \int_{(1,\pi)}^{(2,\pi)}\left (1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}\cos{\frac{y}{x}}\right )dx + \left (\sin{\frac{y}{x}} +\frac{y}{x}\cos{\frac{y}{x}}\right )dy
$$
Show that it is independent of path provided the path does not intersect the `y-axis`.

I can't make heads or tails of the concept of path independence. It says to find a potential function and then I don't understand anything.

I have determined the potential function for this particular problem:
$$
f(x,y) = x + y\sin\frac{y}{x}
$$

What shows independence of path and why can the path Not intersect `y-axis`?

EDIT: I think I understand why the path can't intersect `y-axis` - for then x = 0 and we'd be dividing by 0.

I still can't understand how I can show that the integral is independent of path: isn't the existence of a potential function reason enough?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Green's Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).

Comment: What I managed to read somewhat is that for every point $A,B\in T\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2, \int_{AB} F(x,y)dx + G(x,y)dy$ is independent of path of integration in set $T \Leftrightarrow$ there exists a function $H:T\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $T$ is differentiable and $T_x = F(x,y), T_y = G(x,y)$. Provided this is how I determined the potential function, isn't that adequate to show independence of path?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't show that the potential function is differentiable.